# Changing rspec instance_double return values after each test

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

I am testing a Ruby class with Rspec.  I would like to change an instance double's return values between these two contexts, i.e., I want tallied_data.a_conv, tallied_data.a_nonconv, etc. to return different values for the "when A is winner" context.  Is there any way I can do this without having to create a new instance_double and repeat all of the code in lines 3-9?  Is there a different way to approach this?

```
describe ABSplitTest do
  describe "#test_winner" do
  let(:tallied_data) do
    instance_double("ABDataSummary", 
      a_conv: 50, a_nonconv: 51, 
      b_conv: 52, b_nonconv: 53,
      to_h: { a: { conv: 50, nonconv: 51 }, b: { conv:52, nonconv: 53 } }
    )
  end
  subject(:sample_test) { ABSplitTest.new(tallied_data) }

  context "when there is no winner" do
    it "returns that there is no clear winner" do
      expect(sample_test.test_winner).to \
        eq("No winner at 0.05 significance")
    end
  end

  context "when A is winner" do
    it "returns that A is winner" do
      expect(sample_test.test_winner).to \
        eq("No winner at 0.05 significance")
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you're doing in your tests and how it relates to `tallied_data`, but you can set specific values in your contexts via `let`. `let` values aren't resolved until their first use, so you can compose them from values in inner contexts, if desired.

For example:

```
describe ABSplitTest do
  describe "#test_winner" do
    let(:tallied_data) do
      instance_double("ABDataSummary",
        a_conv: a_conv, a_nonconv: 51,
        b_conv: 52, b_nonconv: 53,
        to_h: { a: { conv: 50, nonconv: 51 }, b: { conv:52, nonconv: 53 } }
      )
    end
    subject(:sample_test) { ABSplitTest.new(tallied_data) }

    context "when there is no winner" do
      let(:a_conv) { 50 }
      it "returns that there is no clear winner" do
        expect(sample_test.test_winner).to \
          eq("No winner at 0.05 significance")
      end
    end

    context "when A is winner" do
      let(:a_conv) { 70 }
      it "returns that A is winner" do
        expect(sample_test.test_winner).to \
          eq("No winner at 0.05 significance")
      end
    end
```